# Oidc-Client js - Frame window timed out - Silent sign in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oidc-client-js

In `app.js` I hava an `AuthorizationInterceptor`that checks if user is logged in. When the users token expires it hits the err condition and errors with `Frame window timed out` (see below) and then goes in to a redirect loop. I want to to do a silent sign in but I guess the iframe is erroring. I cannot see that it ever redirects to the `silent-callback.html` - it only hits `callback.html`:

```
app.factory("AuthorizationInterceptor", ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$window', 'authService', function ($q, $injector, $rootScope, $window, authService) {

    var request = function (requestSuccess) {

        var currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var oidcManager = window.translation.oidcUserManager;

                oidcManager.getUser().then(function (u) {
                    if (u) {

                        if (u['expires_at'] < currentTime + 10) {
                            oidcManager.signinSilent()
                                .then(function (user) {
                                    requestSuccess.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + user["access_token"];
                                    deferred.resolve(requestSuccess);
                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.log('getuser error' + err);  //this logs the below error.
                                    authService.login();
                                    deferred.resolve(true);
                                });
                        } else {
                            console.log('AuthInterceptor requestSuccess.headers');
                            requestSuccess.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + u["access_token"];
                            deferred.resolve(requestSuccess);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        authService.login();
                        deferred.resolve(true);
                    }
                });
                return deferred.promise;

    };
```

Error message logged to console:

```
getuser errorError: Frame window timed out  app.js:92:41

Error: c.paramSerializer is not a function
p@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:88:204
n/h<@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:86:245
f/<@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:118:334
$eval@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:132:448
$digest@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:129:455
$evalAsync/<@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:133:30
e@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:43:93
Hf/l.defer/c<@http://localhost:5050/lib/angular/angular.min.js:45:491
```

This is my setup and function for `authService.login()`

```
 var config = {
        authority: url,
        client_id: "js",
        redirect_uri: url + "/LocalizationAdmin/callback.html",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile api1",
        post_logout_redirect_uri: url + "/LocalizationAdmin/index.html",
        silent_redirect_uri: url + "/LocalizationAdmin/silent-callback.html",
        automaticSilentRenew: true
    };

 function login() {
        mgr.getUser().then(function (u) {
            if (u) {
                var currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

                if (u['expires_at'] < currentTime + 10) {
                    mgr.signinSilent()
                        .then(function (user) {
                            var idToken = user.id_token;
                            var dataIdToken = getDataFromToken(idToken);

                        }, function (err) {
                            mgr.signinRedirect();
                        });
                }
            }
            else {
                mgr.signinRedirect();
            }
        });
```

Extremely stuck on this one - any help appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your silent_redirect_uri is also setup in your identity provider such as identity server? The identity provider will try to verify this value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the silent renew URL (.../silent-renew.html) to the list of allowed redirect URIs in your IdentityServer?